# error while generating apk file from react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 33s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: I would recommend following the suggestions given in your error message itself. Try re-running your build with --debug or --stacktrace to get an idea of what went wrong and then try fixing it.

Comment: Try cd android && ./gradlew clean --info then generate APk from Android studio

Comment: [Check this out if it solves your Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450887/13379286)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a problem with your build.gradle version at root :

1-Open Android Studio
2-Open the android folder of you project
3-android studio will upgrade the gradle version automatically (make sure it does)
4-try again to generate apk