# Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED in bundle

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make `app.aab` but i don't know whats wrong here i am keep getting this exception.

React native version is : 0.62.2
command i am using `./gradlew bundleRelease`
also i try to follow this [link](https://shift.infinite.red/handling-64-bit-android-builds-for-react-native-2fcd7a2e5c14) but same issue again.
help please...

[image: exception]

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue. When I tried to build the apk using `./gradlew assembleRelease` command, it fails at `app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` and returns non zero exit value. I finally found a solution using these steps.

First check if assets folder is exists or not in `android/app/src/main` location, if not then create a new one name it **'assets'**. If it exists already then check whether it contains file named `index.android.bundle`, if yes then delete it and if not then proceed.

Start from your root directory: `C:\Users\user_name\AppName`

1. `cd android`
2. `./gradlew clean`
3. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`  It creates the `index.android.bundle` named bundle file in assets folder.
4. `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` it will gives you the release apk at `android\app\build\outputs\apk\release` location.
5. `./gradlew bundleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` it will gives you the aab file of your project.

*These steps solved my problem. Please try and tell me if it works*

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to solve this issue from many days but thanks it still worked lol.

Answer (score 2):

1. `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
2. `gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

Comment: thanks for your response , but the command you have written it will generate an APK , but i want `app.aab` bundle to upload on play store